# Create new fields and also creating their relationship from the MODEL, it is creating multiple fields with same name

Tags: neo4j

When I am going to create new fields and also creating their relationship from the MODEL, it is creating multiple fields with same name and creating their relationship from MODEL.

Before execute the Cypher statement below is the cypher statement.

```
Match (XYZ_Security:MODEL { NodeID: '8e21d265-ae61-4fbe-9664-d4c8177c5792' }) 
SET XYZ_Security.Name = 'XYZ_Security', 
    XYZ_Security.IsLookup = 'True', 
    XYZ_Security.NodeID = '8e21d265-ae61-4fbe-9664-d4c8177c5792' 
WITH 1 AS IGNORED 
Match (CUSIP:FIELD { NodeID: '92bce26d-5957-4a2c-9ee7-adcf6f5f3a46' }) 
SET CUSIP.Name = 'CUSIP', 
    CUSIP.IsKeyMember = 'False', 
    CUSIP.IsValueMember = 'False', 
    CUSIP.DataType = 'string', 
    CUSIP.LookupItem = '', 
    CUSIP.ValidationExpressionText = 'CUSIP != null', 
    CUSIP.ValidationExpressionValue = 'true', 
    CUSIP.NodeID = '92bce26d-5957-4a2c-9ee7-adcf6f5f3a46' 
WITH 1 AS IGNORED 
Match (ISIN:FIELD { NodeID: 'c0c15fb2-6535-4a23-9c3d-757e35fef063' }) 
SET ISIN.Name = 'ISIN', 
    ISIN.IsKeyMember = 'False', 
    ISIN.IsValueMember = 'False', 
    ISIN.DataType = 'string', 
    ISIN.LookupItem = '', 
    ISIN.ValidationExpressionText = 'ISIN != null', 
    ISIN.ValidationExpressionValue = 'true', 
    ISIN.NodeID = 'c0c15fb2-6535-4a23-9c3d-757e35fef063' 
WITH 1 AS IGNORED 
Match (CurrencyCode:FIELD { NodeID: 'b7bde796-36c1-4d0a-b972-bcc73a4112cd' }) 
SET CurrencyCode.Name = 'CurrencyCode',
    CurrencyCode.IsKeyMember = 'False', 
    CurrencyCode.IsValueMember = 'False', 
    CurrencyCode.DataType = 'Lookup', 
    CurrencyCode.LookupItem = 'Currency', 
    CurrencyCode.ValidationExpressionText = 'CurrencyCode != null', 
    CurrencyCode.ValidationExpressionValue = 'true', 
    CurrencyCode.NodeID = 'b7bde796-36c1-4d0a-b972-bcc73a4112cd' 
WITH 1 AS IGNORED 
Match (Country:FIELD { NodeID: 'b7bde796-36c1-4d0a-b972-bcc73a4112cd' }) 
SET Country.Name = 'Country', 
    Country.IsKeyMember = 'False', 
    Country.IsValueMember = 'False', 
    Country.DataType = 'Lookup', 
    Country.LookupItem = 'Currency', 
    Country.ValidationExpressionText = 'CurrencyCode != null', 
    Country.ValidationExpressionValue = 'true', 
    Country.NodeID = 'b7bde796-36c1-4d0a-b972-bcc73a4112cd' 
WITH 1 AS IGNORED 
MATCH (XYZ_Security:FIELD) 
WHERE XYZ_Security.NodeID IN ['4ba763fb-dd53-4cc4-a151-61e0b2fc364c'] 
OPTIONAL MATCH (XYZ_Security) <-[r]-(x) 
DELETE XYZ_Security, r 
WITH 1 AS IGNORED 
Match (XYZ_Security:MODEL { NodeID: '8e21d265-ae61-4fbe-9664-d4c8177c5792' }) 
Create (CADIS_ID_SEC:FIELD { Name: 'CADIS_ID_SEC', 
  IsKeyMember: 'False', IsValueMember: 'False', DataType: 'Lookup', 
  LookupItem: 'CADIS_ID_SEC', 
  ValidationExpressionText: 'CADIS_ID_SEC != null', 
  ValidationExpressionValue: 'true', 
  NodeID: '5fe062aa-7d47-451e-b091-8cc4a4c8c181' }) 
Create (XYZ_Security)-[:HAS_FIELD]->(CADIS_ID_SEC)
```

After executing the above cypher statement, it is adding multiple FIELDs with same name and also adding their relationship with MODEL. Please refer to the below screen cap below from after the cypher statement is executed.

[image]

Comment: Your image does not show any nodes with the same displayed value ("name" property?). Is that the right image?

Comment: Well there is a copy-paste problem with node id `b7bde796-36c1-4d0a-b972-bcc73a4112cd`. You're using the same node for both your CurrencyCode and Country data, you'll want to review and fix up these sections in your query. Other than this, please go into more detail for the issue you're seeing, it's not clear from your description and the image.

Comment: Hi Dave, my issue has been resolved, actually I was using the duplicate the NodeID, so just because of that it was creating duplicate nodes.